# Merging two fields together for use as a composite key in one table but foreign in another?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

So I have two tables, one called invest and one called users. Users can sign up and have an 'ID' assigned to them which is unique as well as their username which is non unique. I have joined these two together to create a composite key.

In the `invest` table a user can insert through a form investment details, and the username is requested via `$_SESSION["username"];` and inserted into the `invest` table. Is there a way to link the two `ID` fields together? So that the `ID` from `users` is linked with `username` thereby updating the `ID` column in `invest` whenever the `username` is inserted there.

```
 CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `trn_date` datetime NOT NULL,
 `firstname` text NOT NULL,
 `secondname` text NOT NULL,
 `address` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `age` smallint(3) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`username`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


 CREATE TABLE `invest` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `trn_date` datetime NOT NULL,
 `income` int(6) NOT NULL,
 `Shariah` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `emerging` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `risk` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Not very experienced with SQl so apologies if my question is vague or misunderstood.

Comment: instead of inserting `username` into `invest` you should find out what the `users.id` and insert that into the `invest` table instead.

Comment: tried that, the thing is `id` is assigned when the details are add to the database, it isn't declared in the php. So `$_SESSION["id"];` won't work

Comment: `SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = :username`

Answer (score 0):

After inserting the user record during signup, you can fetch the id generated for that record using `mysql_insert_id()` and store it in session. 
`mysql_insert_id()`returns -

- the ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query on success
- 0 if the previous query does not generate an AUTO_INCREMENT value
- FALSE if no MySQL connection was established.

Example code:

```
<?php
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db('mydb');

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')");
    $id = mysqli_insert_id();
    $_SESSION['generatedId'] = $id;
    //Now you can use this value from session
?>
```

Comment: in my case im using mysqli, could you please provide an example using that? and including $_SESSION? Thanks

Comment: Updated answer to address your case.